# SQL Query on Duplicates Self join table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in MS Access and I have to find duplicate Emails where Channel and Policy type is different.

I wrote below query but it is not working the way i want to. It does have duplicate values in Channel and Policy type as well.

So results are looks like this;

```
Email           Channel     Policy
xyz@abc.com     IA      H
xyz@abc.com     IA      P
```

**What I want results should be like;**

```
Email           Channel     Policy
xyz@abc.com     IA      H
xyz@abc.com     DIR     P
```

Here is the query;

```
SELECT Master.Email, Master.Channel, Master.PolicyNumber, Master.PolicyType
FROM Master
WHERE (((Master.Email) In 
(SELECT [Email] 
FROM [Master] As Tmp 
GROUP BY [Email] 
HAVING Count(*)>1 )))
ORDER BY Master.Email;
```

Comment: could you add some sample data from your table?

Comment: Group by Master.Email, Master.Channel